# Azure web app service Django server log

Tags: django, azure, logging, server, internal-server-error

I have been working with Azure's web app service using Resource Manager to deploy a Django app.  It has been working in fits and starts.  I really like the auto-deployment from GitHub but I have been frustrated by the ability to work with the underlying machine.  There is a "Console" tool through the Azure portal but it has limited functionality and when there is an internal server error on my app, I can't find the server output log.

Can someone share insight into how to view the server logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure web apps have a number of logs however, the applications logs provided out of the box only support Asp.Net applications. That being said there is an article about django on web apps and how to store and view its logs [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/08/04/debug-django-web-application-in-azure-web-apps/).

What'll you'll have to do, as described in the link, is to setup the django application to store its logs on the azure file system. Another option is to setup the django application to email the devs but the better option is to store the logs on the file system properly.